# AngularJS directive loosing the variable value after filtering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Am having a stopwatch with different titles, when I start a watch it runs and after 10 seconds it pops an alert.I can filter the watch on top of title, when I reset the filter the running watch is not displaying the time but it pops an alert at 10 seconds. Why the binding is not working after filter?What am doing wrong here?How can I fix it?
Find the  [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/BQLIXeremyPYiJq8aSkv?p=preview) Complete code and HTML is in plunker.

Clicking play will start the watch, pause will pause it and stop - stops the watch.

```
< script type = "text/javascript" > angular.module('App', [])
        .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $interval) {
        $interval(function () {
            $scope.sharedTime = new Date();
        }, 500);
    })
        .directive('stopwatch', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            templateUrl: 'stopwatch.html',
            scope: {
                // Set title in the isolate scope from the title attribute on the     directive's element.
                title: '@title',
                // Set up a bi-directional binding between currentTime on the local scope and the parent
                // scope's variable containing the current time that's the value of the time attribute.
                currentTime: '=time'
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {},
            controllerAs: 'swctrl',
            controller: function ($scope, $interval) {
                var self = this;
                var time = 0;
                var mode = 1;
                var status = 0;
                var timer_id;
                self.play = 1;
                self.start = function (interval) {
                    self.play = 0;
                    var timeRet;
                    interval = 1000;
                    if (status == 0) {
                        status = 1;

                        function timeRun() {
                            if (time < 86400) {
                                time++;
                                timeRet = self.getElapsedMs();
                                if (time == 10) {
                                    alert("Its 10 seconds")
                                }

                                if (typeof (callback) === 'function') callback(timeRet);
                            }
                        };
                        return timer_id = setInterval(timeRun, interval);
                    }

                };

                self.pause = function () {
                    self.play = 1;
                    if (status == 1) {
                        status = 0;
                        clearInterval(timer_id);
                    }
                };

                self.stop = function () {
                    self.play = 1;
                    sec = (typeof (sec) !== 'undefined') ? sec : 0;
                    time = sec;
                    if (status == 1) {
                        status = 0;
                        clearInterval(timer_id);
                    }


                };

                self.getTime = function () {
                    return time;
                };



                self.getElapsedMs = function () {

                    var second = time % 60;
                    var minute = Math.floor(time / 60) % 60;
                    var hour = Math.floor(time / 3600) % 60;

                    second = (second < 10) ? '0' + second : second;
                    minute = (minute < 10) ? '0' + minute : minute;
                    hour = (hour < 10) ? '0' + hour : hour;

                    var timeObj = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second

                    return timeObj;
                };
            }
        }
    }); < /script>
```

**How to reproduce**: Activate one, then type in "two" in the textbox, then erase it. You'll see that the one timer is showing 00:00:00

Comment: It seems OK to me. Pause/Play and Stop/Play both increment the seconds and show the alert at 10 seconds.

Comment: @camden_kid I too didn't notice at start. Try to activate `one`, then type in "two" in the textbox, then erase it. You'll see that the `one` timer is showing 00:00:00.

Comment: Yes, I see. It might be worth putting your comment in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Filter in `ng-repeat` applies your filtering keyword on the array and returns a new subset, thus destroying previously created directives.

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

> Selects a subset of items from array and returns it as a new array.

If you place inside the link function:

```
scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
    console.log("destroying");
});
```

You'll see that it logs for every stopwatch that is eliminated due to the filtering.

Therefore, I'd just hide the entire div of the stopwatch instead of using the filter:

```
<div  ng-show="!filter || title.indexOf(filter) > -1">
    <div class="timer" >{{title}}<br>
       {{swctrl.getElapsedMs() | limitTo:6}}<span class="sec">
       {{swctrl.getElapsedMs() | limitTo:-2}}</span>

   </div>
  <a href="" ng-show ="swctrl.play" id="timerPlay" class="play" ng-click="swctrl.start();"> Play</a>
  <a href=""  ng-show ="!swctrl.play" id="timerPause" class="pause"  ng-click="swctrl.pause();">Pause</a>
  <a href=""  id="timerStop" class="stop" ng-click="swctrl.stop();" >Stop</a>    
</div>
```

And your usage becomes:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in arr">
     <div stopwatch title="{{item}}" filter="filters" time="sharedTime">
</div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/T0YxtW80Z1BUeXOg1z1B?p=info)

Answer (score 0):

Omri Aharon explained what the issue is. Personally I'd move the stopwatch functionality into a factory and pass instances of this into your directive.

```
.factory('StopWatch', function() {
    function StopWatch(name) {
      this.name = name;
      this.time = 0;
      this.mode = 1;
      this.status = 0;
      this.play = 1;
    }

    StopWatch.prototype.start = function(interval) {

      var self = this;
      self.play = 0;

      var timeRet;


      interval = 1000;  
      if(self.status == 0)
      {
        self.status = 1;
        function timeRun()
        {       
            if(self.time < 86400)
            {
              self.time++;
              timeRet =  self.getElapsedMs();
              if(self.time == 10)
              {
                alert("Its 10 seconds")
              }

              if(typeof(callback) === 'function') callback(timeRet);
            }               
        };
        return self.timer_id = setInterval(timeRun, interval);     
      }

    };

    StopWatch.prototype.pause = function() {
      this.play = 1;
      if(this.status == 1)
      {
        this.status = 0;
        clearInterval(this.timer_id);
      }
    };

    StopWatch.prototype.stop = function() {
      this.play = 1;
      var sec = (typeof(sec) !== 'undefined') ? sec : 0;
      this.time = sec;
      if(this.status == 1)
      {
        this.status = 0;
        clearInterval(this.timer_id);
      }
    };

    StopWatch.prototype.getTime = function() {
      return this.time;
    };

    StopWatch.prototype.getElapsedMs = function() {

      var second = this.time % 60;
      var minute = Math.floor(this.time / 60) % 60;
      var hour = Math.floor(this.time / 3600) % 60;

      second = (second < 10) ? '0'+second : second;
      minute = (minute < 10) ? '0'+minute : minute;
      hour = (hour < 10) ? '0'+hour : hour;

      var timeObj = hour+":"+minute+":"+second

      return timeObj;

    };

    return StopWatch;
})
```

So you'd create the stopwatches:

```
$scope.timers = [
  new StopWatch('one'),
  new StopWatch('two'),
  new StopWatch('three'),
  new StopWatch('four')
];
```

Then repeat and pass into the directive:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in timers | filter:filter_">
  {{item.name}}
  <div stopwatch="item"></div>
</div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qctY55It1RJQWbS4OGtc?p=preview)